# Vector of Arrays of Objects - push_back()

Tags: c++, vector

as name of thread says I have problem with adding elements to my vector... Very similar construction works perfectly (Array of Vectors of Objects)

```
    Game.h

    class Game: parent, stan
    {
    public:

        (...)
            struct lista_boardow

            {
             stan tabliczka[8][8];
            };


            std::vector<lista_boardow> _lista_boardow;
        (...)

static int AiMove(std::vector<lista_boardow>& vect, stan _b[][8]);

        (...)
```

And second one:

```
    Game.cpp

    (...)
int Game::AiMove(std::vector<lista_boardow>& vect, stan tym_board[][8])
{
    stan tabi[8][8];

    (...)

    vect.push_back(tabi); // ?????

    }
    (...)
```

Error I get:

```
error C2664: 'void std::vector<_Ty>::push_back(_Ty &&)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'stan [8][8]' to 'Game::lista_boardow &&'
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Where is the declaration of `vect` ?

Comment: `std::vector<lista_boardow> _lista_boardow;` should be probably better `std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<stan>>> _lista_boardow;` or `std::vector<std::array<std::array<stan,8>,8>> _lista_boardow;`

Comment: Ah, sorry, my bad, edited post :)

@ πάντα ῥεῖ

Thanks but how to add tab[8][8] to std::vector<std::array<std::array<stan,8>,8>> _lista_boardow; ?

Comment: @user3677394 _'but how to add `tab[8][8]` to ..._ Check the [`std::array<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) documentation, what conversions are possible and how.

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are but i'm not very familiar with multi dimensional vectors, could you be so kind and give me example ?

Answer (score 1):

What kind of problem do you have?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

struct elem {
    int value;
    elem(int value) : value(value) {}
};

struct nih_array {
    elem data[2][2];
};

int main() {
    vector<nih_array> v;
    v.push_back({1, 2, 3, 4});
    cout << v[0].data[1][0].value << endl; // "3", no problem here
}
```

[Live version.](http://ideone.com/1fxiS0)